# mixing an integer and string in an ssis derived column

Tags: ssis, expression, derived

I have an issue in creating a derived column that I can't seem to figure out.  It's simple SQL, but in SSIS I can't seem to do it.

Basically it is checking for a value greater than zero, and assigning a string result. The resul needs to be wrapped in a string as well.

Example:

"Indicator=\"" + [IND] > 0 ? "CP" : "" + "\""

Should yield:

Indicator = "CP"  if IND is 20.00
or 
Indicator = "" if IND is 0

I cannot seem to mix the If/Then with the strings.  Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 4):

You were on the right track. I believe the expression you were looking for was

```
(DT_STR,2,1252)((IND > 0) ? "CP" : "")
```

If the value of IND is greater than zero, then use the string CP; else use empty string. That expression will get placed inside of a Derived Column Task.

String operations in SSIS are going to result in Unicode strings, DT_WSTR, as the return type. Thus I am wrapping the entire results of our expression with an explicit cast back to a non-unicode string type with the `(DT_STR, 2, 1252)` call.

In the event that NULL reaches this expression, it will result in a NULL in your output. Whether that's desirable is up to you. If it is not, then you'll need to test for it `ISNULL([IND])` and then make it take whichever path makes sense CP or empty string.

### Source query

I created a simple package with the following source query

```
SELECT 20.0 AS IND UNION ALL SELECT 0;
```

I then fed the output of that into a Derived Column which uses the expression defined above and then put a data viewer on the output of that to demonstrate the results are matching the expectation.

### Results

Screen capture of my package

[image]

### Biml

For those following along at home, you can build this package by 
1. adding a Biml file to your SSIS project (after installing [BIDS Helper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/)) and pasting the following content into the resulting file (overwriting the existing declaration). 
2. Edit the value of the ConnectionString to point to a valid SQL Server installation.
3. Right click on the Biml file and generate SSIS package will result in a package called `so_20645240`

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <Connections>
        <!-- Change ConnectionString below. Privider if not 2012, Data Source for certain -->
        <OleDbConnection
            Name="Src"
            ConnectionString="Data Source=localhost\dev2012;Initial Catalog=tempdb;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;"
            />
    </Connections>
    <Packages>
        <Package Name="so_20645240" ConstraintMode="Linear">
            <Variables>
                <Variable Name="QuerySource" DataType="String">SELECT 20.0 AS IND UNION ALL SELECT 0; </Variable>
            </Variables>
        <Tasks>
            <Dataflow Name="DFT Source">
                <Transformations>
                    <OleDbSource Name="OLE_SRC Query" ConnectionName="Src"
                >
                    <VariableInput VariableName="User.QuerySource" />
                </OleDbSource>
                <DerivedColumns Name="DER Expressions">
                    <Columns>
                        <Column Name="Indicator" DataType="String" Length="2">(DT_STR, 2, 1252)(([IND] &gt; 0) ? "CP" : "")</Column>
                    </Columns>
                </DerivedColumns>
                </Transformations>
            </Dataflow>
        </Tasks>
        </Package>
    </Packages>
</Biml>
```

Comment: Greetings anonymous DownVoter ([@TheOptimusPrimus](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2517150/theoptimusprimus)) This answer has been marked as "not useful". I generate the requested results, provide reproducible methods for arriving at this conclusion so could you help me understand what would make this a useful answer?

Comment: Welcome back anonymous DownVoter ([@TheOptimusPrimus](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2517150/theoptimusprimus)) I was happy to see your heart had not swelled with the pending holidays. If you could provide guidance on what makes this a not useful answer instead of petty serial downvoting, please leave a comment.

Comment: Tks Bill, esp for the BIML :-)